# React Native: Como selecionar o próximo TextInput depois de pressionar o botão "next" do teclado?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Utilizo componente Input para inserir dados no form principal, de acordo com o código abaixo.

```
import React from "react";
import { TextInput, View } from "react-native";

const Input = ({
    placeholder,
    value,
    onChangeText,
    keyboardType,
    returnKeyType,
    onSubmitEditing,
    blurOnSubmit,
}) => {
    const { containerStyle, inputStyle } = styles;
    state = { isFocused: true }
    return (
        <View style={containerStyle}>
            <TextInput
                placeholder={placeholder}
                autoCorrect={false}
                blurOnSubmit={blurOnSubmit}
                autoFocus={false}
                style={inputStyle}
                value={value}
                onChangeText={onChangeText}
                onSubmitEditing={onSubmitEditing}
                keyboardType={keyboardType}
                returnKeyType={returnKeyType}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

No form principal tenho 2 campos do tipo TextInput ( componente Input acima ) na qual preciso que ao clicar no botão NEXT do teclado o cursor vá automaticamente para o próximo Input.
Porém, esta retornando o erro "_this2.secondInput.focus is not a function".

Já fiz várias alterações propostas no forum mas não obtive sucesso.

Versão do React Native: 0.59.5

Versão React: 18.8.3

Abaixo código do form principal.

Input 1

```
 <Input
              placeholder={"kg"}
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              keyboardType="number-pad"
              returnKeyType={"next"}
              blurOnSubmit={false}
              value={this.state.peso}
              onChangeText={peso => this.setState({ peso })}
              onSubmitEditing={() => this.secondInput.focus()}
            />
```

Input 2

```
<Input
              placeholder={"mc ou mcg"}
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              keyboardType="number-pad"
              returnKeyType={"next"}
              value={this.state.dose}
              blurOnSubmit={false}
              onChangeText={dose => this.setState({ dose })}
              ref={ref => {
                this.secondInput = ref;
              }}
            />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar uma referência ao segundo input e focá-lo quando o primeiro input for "enviado" através da propriedade [`onSubmitEditing`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onsubmitediting).

**Segundo input**

```
// Adicionar a referencia ao segundo input

ref={(input) => { this.input_2 = input; }}
```

**Primeiro input**

```
// Adiciona a função para focar no input_2 quando o 
// botão de enviar do teclado for pressionado

onSubmitEditing={() => { this.input_2.focus(); }}

// Definir como falso a propriedade blurOnSubmit para que o campo a seguir continue focado 

blurOnSubmit={false}
```

Por fim um código básico de exemplo:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
        placeholder="Primeiro input"
        returnKeyType = {"next"}
        onSubmitEditing={() => { this.input_2.focus(); }}
        blurOnSubmit={false}
    />
    <TextInput
        ref={(input) => { this.input_2 = input; }}
        placeholder="Segundo input"
    />
</View>
```

[Demonstração online](https://snack.expo.io/@sant0will/d4f9e3)